# My servo wont follow my cam

Tags: python

So i am trying to make the servo follow my face which will end up my camera following my face

But the servo isnt doing anything please look at this
(Also im only using Horizontal because I would like to start off with that first)

Question : how do i make it so it can move, what am i doing wrong?

Python code : https://pastebin.com/V6SegsQj

Arduino code :

```
#include<Servo.h>
Servo servoHor; //Horizontal Servo
int x;
int prevX;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  servoHor.attach(6); //Attach Horizontal Servo to Pin 6
  servoHor.write(90);
}

void Pos()
{
  if(prevX != x)
  {
    int servoX = map(x, 600, 0, 70, 179); 
    servoX = min(servoX, 179);
    servoX = max(servoX, 70);
    servoHor.write(servoX);
  }
}

void loop()
{
  if(Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    if(Serial.read() == 'X')
    {
      x = Serial.parseInt();
    }
    while(Serial.available() > 0)
    {
      Serial.read();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `Pos()` is never being called. It can't ever do anything.